# Can I name the repos on Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For various reasons (out-of-scope of this question) I'm syncing from three different git repos. I get output along the lines of:

```
Revision: ddea6b5bf995f466b5a9933ed3903a334eb83d26
    ides2-326b-coding-standards
Revision: 81a894cda7b4e6403f2d4394ffb1fbf829ca18d1
    refs/remotes/origin/develop
Revision: 27a8762ab78446a6f2bb805cc440d75b9e25c28c
    refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

It would be nice to somehow show either the name of each repo, or perhaps its path. As the build system admin, I know the order of the checkout calls, so can interpret, but the other engineers probably won't. Does anybody know how to add extra information to this list?

If it matters, it is a scripting pipeline.

Comment: The path is what jenkins is showing there for example: refs/remotes/origin/develop . This is the path inside your current project: yourproject/refs/remotes/origin/develop

Comment: I understand that. What I've after is some way of naming a repo in this list, or perhaps of giving the url.